# HttpClient.SendAsync: 500 - Internal Server Error in Windows Service Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http

I am seeing the following message in attempting to post a json string to a web API (this is what is written to file in the line containing System.IO.File.WriteAllText):

```
Response: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 21:26:12 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 36
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}
```

The code within my async posting method is as follows:

```
  Uri theUri = new Uri("http://www.website.com/WebsiteAPI/PostDetails");

  HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
  aClient.BaseAddress = theUri;
  aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
      Convert.ToBase64String(
      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
      string.Format("{0}:{1}", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"))));
  aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = theUri.Host;

  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, theUri);
  request.Content = new StringContent(resource, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

  // Post the data 
  aClient.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
      {
          System.IO.File.WriteAllText(PROFILE_JSON_PATH, "Response: " + responseTask.Result);
      });
```

I've tried many different solutions online but nothing seems to work.  Any idea why this may not be working?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is something with your Web API that is erroring.  You may or may not have something wrong with your client code--but you'll have to go to the Web API for information that could explain what the problem is.